# How to compile and run with this folder structure

Tags: java, javac

I have my java source files in src/net/... folders and .jar files in lib folder. How to compile and run this files with command line without writing build script ?

Comment: you will find this link useful http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/using-javac-and-java-commands-to-compile-and-launch-java-programs/

Comment: Don't forget to include [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) or where you are having problems. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Also please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say you have your code files in

```
[someDirectory]
  |
  +-[lib]
  |  |
  |  +-someLib.jar
  |  +-someOtherLib.jar
  |  +-...
  |
  +--[src]
       |
       +-[net]
           |
           +-[name]
                |
                +-[one]
                   |
                   +-[two]
                       |
                       +-[main]
                           |
                           +-Main.java <- code you want to compile
                                          and execute
```

then if your console is in

```
someDirectory>
```

you can compile it with

```
someDirectory>javac -cp "lib\*" src\net\name\one\two\main\Main.java
```

but this will produce `Main.class` file in same directory as `Main.java` so to execute code from `net.name.one.two.main.Main` class you would need to include `src` directory to classPath because this directory contains package that `Main` class is placed, so you would need to use command

```
someDirectory>java -cp "src;lib\*" net.name.one.two.main.Main
```

---

But it is good practice to separate class files from source files. To do this you can add `-d` (directory) parameter while compiling pass directory which should have compiled class files. So first create your `classes` directory at the same level as `src` directory and execute

```
someDirectory>javac -d "classes" -cp "lib\*" src\net\name\one\two\main\Main.java
```

and now to be able to execute your `Main` class instead creating confusion by `src` directory to classPath you will have to add `classes` directory which is more intuitive.

```
someDirectory>java -cp "classes;lib\*" net.name.one.two.main.Main.java
```

Comment: Its compile, but how to run them

Comment: To run Java app you need to compile class with main method using `javac` including all required jars in classpath. When you compile it then just use `java -cp "lib/*" full.name.of.YourClass` from folder that contains your classes structure. Normally it is done by IDE like Eclipse, NetBeans or others.

Comment: Before posting that question i tried that but its not working, it says  that `Error: Could not find or load main class name.one.two.Main`

but when i remove folder structure its working fine.

Comment: Does adding `.` to classpath with `-cp ".;lib/*"` help?

Comment: To help us help you try including in your question example showing which class you are trying to run, where is it placed, in which directory your console operating (in which directory you are in console, like `c:/>`, `c:/someDirectory>`), commands you used till now and exact command that is not working.

Comment: I'm not authorized to do that. My problem is its perfectly compiling. With javac, but i use this `java -cp .:lib/* name.one.two.Main` run several projects but this is not working or this project, why is that?

Comment: Will need to somehow recreate environment that would reproduce your problem but unfortunately now I am not able to do it. Will try to help you when I find some free time. Sorry :(.

Comment: Thanks mate. Great help. For the time being i'm removing my folder structure and moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
javac -cp .;lib/lib1.jar;lib/lib2.jar src/net/*.java
```

lib1 and lib2 are your libraries. It assume your libraries are in lib folder. You may also need to change the destination folder for .class files.

To run the application use

```
java -cp bin;lib/lib1.jar;lib/lib2.jar net.mypackage.MyMainclass
```

net...

It assume your .class files are in bin folder.

Comment: To Run use `java -cp bin;lib/lib1.jar;lib/lib2.jar YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME`  .It assume your `.class` files are in bin folder.

Comment: But it not working properly program exits by giving several errors

Comment: Errors means there are some command line arguments to start the programme. By using your method it does not request them.

Comment: Hi MadhuSilva I just tried it and came out that Instead of your package name put the class path like `net.mypackage.MyMainClass`