# Query about packages

Tags: java, import, package

I know that `import example.*`  will import all the classes and interfaces in the package example. So is it necessary to use the `*` only when there are 2 or more classes in the example package?

Because in my program there was only 1 class, `xyz`, in the package example, and when I tried to use it in other program by `import example.*;`, the `xyz` class was not accessible.

Instead if I used it like - `import example.xyz`, then only it was accessible in other programs. But the usual `import java.util.*` and other commands work just fine. So is it because they have multiple classes and interfaces in those packages and only then should the `*` be used?
edit:package code

```
package myPackage;
public class abcd
{
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("this is from package");
    }
}
```

program

```
import myPackage.*;
class ghg
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

    abcd x=new abcd();
    x.show();
    }
}
```

error

```
ghg.java:7: cannot access abcd
bad class file: .\abcd.class
class file contains wrong class: myPackage.abcd
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath
```

EDIT: So i was keeping ghg.java in bin folder of jdk..I moved them out both package and ghg.java and put them in different directory and it worked.

Comment: Was class xyz declared as public?

Comment: @yogidilip Surely it must've been public if he could access it using import.example.xyz?

Comment: Yes.. i declared xyz as public in the example package.

Comment: A star means *all classes* in the package. Whether there are none or hundreds is irrelevant.

Comment: Then why was the class not accessible when I imported it like that?

Comment: Works for me http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMN1BYekE0TmFUZHM

Comment: To get proper answers post (1) [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE] and (2) error message you are getting. You can also include your project structure.

Comment: Show us the code and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I guess: you have a typo somewhere then!

Comment: For now possible problem could be that you have few classes with same name `xyz` in different packages. Just like in case of `List` in Java, we have `java.util.List` and `java.awt.List`. If we add use `import java.util.*; import java.awt.*` and will write `List list;` compiler will still not know which List exactly we want to use here. That is why it is better to explicitly import each type instead of using `*`.

Comment: Edit: just added the code @rudy

Comment: And the same code works just fine if I import it like import myPackage.abcd;

Comment: It works for me. How are you compiling/running this code? Where exactly are your classes located?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin` is location containing `java.exe` and `javac.exe`. It is usually included in `path` environment variable so we could simply use `java.exe` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe`. But that is not what I am asking. Java uses its own `-classpath` (or shorter `-cp`) parameter to describe location of directories containing packages which classes are needed while running or compiling. So it looks like you didn't set it right or that your project structure is invalid (like is `abcd.class` inside `myPackage` directory?).

Comment: of course.. myPackage contains the abcd.class .. how else would i be able to successfully execute the same code when using import myPackage.abcd;

Comment: Post location of your `.java` and `.class` files. Are you using console to run compilation commands? How exactly that command look like and from where you are executing it?

Comment: the .java and .class files are all in bin folder path as i mentioned above..and i'm executing it in cmd prompt. C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin> javac ghg.java

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin` is not meant to hold your project files. It is meant to hold *tools* to create Java projects. Move *your* files out of there and put them in your own directory like `c:\myJava\project1`. Also post exact commands you are using.

Comment: Okay didn't know that..I used to run all my programs up till now like this and it ws fine...So i just moved my ghg.java out of the bin folder and put it somewhere else and it compiles successfully now.. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Here is my previous answer about how you can organize your project to make your life easier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18740577/1393766. Example shown there is based on one posted in question. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Anyway IMO in current form your question can't be really answered properly since it doesn't contain all necessary info to reproduce this problem *in question itself* (I am not including comments since people don't usually read them to see if they are facing same problem). So I would say you can delete it since in current form it can't be helpful for others.

Comment: @Vaibhav Kulkarni
You learn Java. No problem. But on SO it is about quality. There are also a lot of professional developers. Please refactor the code that is displayed. Use correct naming conventions (packages/classes). Indent your code correctly. It is the minimum you can do. If you don't maybe (not me) some people will downvote your question to show that it does not enforce minimum quality.

Comment: @Vaibhav Kulkarni
 Btw it is not a good practice to use the package default. It is possible but not encouraged. A class name starting with 'abcd' is totally inappropriate. You have to put some energy to create a good question. On SO you don't put solved into the title. You accept an answer that can be your own answer. If it is solved please accept one of the answers or create your own one with the correct solution.

Comment: Okay @RudyVissers. Sorry I didn't know about the stuff you mentioned. I'm new here.

Comment: @VaibhavKulkarni Just checking my old answers ... do you think my answer helped you? If so, consider accepting it; or letting me know if your problem still exists. Or delete your question. It is simply better to clean up things, and not let half-baked stuff sit around.

Answer (score 0):

Those import statements are just an indication for the compiler to know where to lookup classes you are using within your source code.

In that sense, this is only about *style*. There are no good technical reasons to use one or the other *style*.

But many people consider using "import x.y.*" to be bad practice; they recommend to have "import x.y.Class1", "import x.y.Class2", ...

Reasoning behind that: you, as the human reader are very much interested in understanding the dependencies into other packages. When the wild-card import is used; you have no mean to understand how many classes are really used. As in: if your class needs 50, 100 imports ... that alone would tell you that something is wrong (because your class has way too many dependencies when it is importing 50, 100 other classes). If wildcards are used, you wouldn't know.

As a consequence, tools such as eclipse will by default "roll out" wildcard imports and turn them into specific class imports instead.

Lets be precise: using "import *" is **never** required. It just seems *convenient* at times! And when "import x.y.*" does not work; but "import x.y.z" works; then well, you must have done something wrong!

Comment: That wasn't his question, he wants to know why it worked when doing it specifically, but not with the wildcard i think

Comment: check my edit..i still don't understand whats wrong there