# trying to compile two java files at ubuntu

Tags: java, compiler-errors, ubuntu-14.04

what i'm trying to do is compile two java files but there is no way to accomplish that. I have the next two files.

file: Migration.java

```
package com.migratation;

import com.migration.Application;

public class Migration{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       //code
   }
}
```

file: Application.java

```
package com.migration;

public class Application{
     //code
}
```

I have compiled and it generate two .class file.

```
javac *.java
```

But when i tried to run main java class it's failed and says

```
java Migration
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class Migratation

Comment: from which path are you running the Migration ???

Comment: `java` command expects full class name, not name of file. So try with `java com.migration.Migration`. You may also need to specify location of that (and possibly other) package in `-classpath` or `-cp` argument.

Comment: your first package is migratation while the second package is migration (typo in one of them, they must match)

Comment: For now take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740468/how-to-compile-and-run-with-this-folder-structure/18740577#18740577. Will try to find better duplicate.