# Could not find or load main class on simple Java Soup app

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, classpath

I do the compilation of this simple programm i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505)

```
package com.stackoverflow.q2835505;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    String question = document.select("#question .post-text").text();
    System.out.println("Question: " + question);

    Elements answerers = document.select("#answers .user-details a");
    for (Element answerer : answerers) {
        System.out.println("Answerer: " + answerer.text());
    }
}

}
```

with this command in terminal:

```
javac -cp ./jsoup-1.10.2.jar Test.java
```

but when i try to run it i take this:

> Error:Could not find or load main class

and I can't find the solution, where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Pshemo Please consider reopening this question. He had a `javac` issue beyond the main `java` *classpath* error. I feel my step-by-step answer might benefit others Java beginners as well. (BTW, I already linked to the aforementioned question in my answer). Thanks man!

Comment: @OP `but when i try to run it i take this` you didn't show how you try to *run* it. Your previous command shows how you are trying to *compile* it.

Comment: @PauloMattos What do you mean by "He had a javac issue beyond the main java classpath error"? `javac -cp ./jsoup-1.10.2.jar Test.java` should create proper *.class* file (at least OP doesn't mention any problems with compilation). "Could not find or load main class" is problem with running `main` method from `Test.class` class. To make it possible OP needs to specify location of package which contains it in `-cp`. All of this is explained in general duplicate. Your answer may still help others regardless if question is closed or not so I don't see reason to not let it stay closed as duplicate.

Comment: @Pshemo I was surprised too... On macOS (at least), running `javac`, without the `-d .` option, places the generated `Test.class` in the *current directory* (and not in the expected `com/stackoverflow/q2835505/Test.class` path). This makes tricky to run it using `java`, even when using the full qualified class name. As such, both issues are related...

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18740577

Comment: @Pshemo It doesn't look like a bug at all — its by design! And goes well *beyond* macOS... Check the **-d directory** option info on [Javac man page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCGAJDC).

Comment: @PauloMattos OK, you are right. Will remove comment about bug since it is simply not true (looks like I rely on IDE too much and forgot about `javac` basics).

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into more than one issue here...

**Javac**. To be sure, compile your Java app like this:

```sh
javac -cp ./jsoup-1.10.2.jar -d . Test.java
```

the `-d` option ensures that the compiled class is placed in the corresponding *package* directory:

```
com/stackoverflow/q2835505/Test.class
```

and not on your current directory. Let's [check the man page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCGAJDC) just to be sure (`-d` option):

> Sets the destination directory for class files. The directory must already exist because `javac` does not create it. If a class is part of a package, then `javac` puts the class file in a subdirectory that reflects the package name and creates directories as needed.
>
> If the `-d` option is *not* specified, then `javac` puts each class file in the same directory as the source file from which it was generated.

**Java**. Finally, run it using:

```sh
java -cp .:./jsoup-1.10.2.jar com.stackoverflow.q2835505.Test
```

this runs your app using your current directory (`.`) and `jsoup-1.10.2.jar` as your class path. The current directory is *mandatory* so `java` finds your `Test.class` as well as the JSoup jar.

---

See [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/819340) for a lot more information on the `java` command syntax.

Comment: I've tried a lot of different ways but i can't run it.

Comment: @geo I detected a couple of issues... pls try again when you have a chance.